# Photo Upload and Display PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I have an image upload script as follows:

```
$product = $_POST['name'];
$detail = $_POST['detail'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


if ($name) {
    //start upload process
    $location = "images/" . $name;
    move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $location);
}


$query="INSERT INTO shop_products VALUES ('','$product','$location','$detail','$price','$class','$category','yes')";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

header("location: ../admin/index.php");
```

and the display of the image is as follows:

```
<img class="item-img" src="scripts/images/<? echo $image; ?>" />
```

As you can see if you go to ltyboards.com/boards, the document source provides the appropriate file name for the image, and the image does exist on the server, but nothing is displayed. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just looks like your path is wrong

`scripts/images/images/`

should be

`scripts/images/`